# How close can light be to exposed insulation?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, fire-hazard

I am mounting a few of those porcelain light lamp sockets in my basement between a few joists. The joists are exposed in my basement and one of places I was going to mount one has insulation batting between the joists. If I am mounting the metal ceiling box to a 2x4 between the joist can I just push the 2x4 up into the insulation and then mount the metal box and porcelain socket. I am using LED light bulbs. Am I creating a fire hazard or am I good?

Answer (score 2):

You are good.  Even with normal bulbs this is fine.